# When Use Mock bulder error return like below in PHP unit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, composer-php

```
$this->formatter = $this->getMockBuilder( "TDD\Formatter" )
        ->setMethods( [ 'currencyAmt' ] )
        ->getMock();

    $this->formatter->expects( $this->any() )
        ->method( 'currencyAmt' )
        ->with( $this->anything() )
        ->will( $this->returnArgument( 0 ) );
```

PHPUnit 6.5.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

........

> Fatal error: Cannot use PHPUnit\Framework\MockObject\Invocation as
>   Invocation because the name is already in use in
>   C:\wamp64\www\unit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit-mock-objects\src\Matcher\MethodName.php
>   on line 14

Whats wrong with my code can any help me ?

Comment: you are repeating a method. check your methods

Comment: Nope I don't repeat method inside the testClass I have checked which method you are saying about

Answer (score 0):

Its problem With PHP Version and I have reported in github they have released new version of phpunit-mock-objects If any one similar bug update your phpunit-mock-objects package further details check below link 
 [phpunit-mock-objects](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/issues/394)